# Xcode custom UITableViewCell has unwanted image indentation after selection

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

Using Xcode 6.3.1 and iOS 8.3 (and Swift 1.2 for what it matters here) I created a custom UITableViewCell that includes an UIImageView, and two UILabels. The whole thing has been formatted using Auto-Layout. No errors, no warnings. When I run the app, all goes fine until... I selected a table row. In that case the image indents a little (simply selection, no editing enabled) and remains indented.

See the first row of the image to get an impression:

[image: Example from app]

Hiding the image removes the problem, and setting the UITableViewCell's Selection parameter (in Xcode) to None also removes the problem (but that feels unnatural when selecting a row).

I am not sure whether it is Auto Layout related as it only appears after selecting the row, but I do not know how to fix it properly. Any ideas?

Edit: here is my cell code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(customCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    let item = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel!.text = item.title
    cell.subtitleLabel?.text = item.subTitle
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: item.icon)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just discovered that rotating the device (simulator) does the same, but for all the imageviews, which makes it look decent again but still has the indentation.

Comment: Could you provide your cell's code? It would be related to the autolayout code.

Comment: This is my test code. http://tempdusty.qiniudn.com/TestCellSelect.zip I do not encounter what you say. Please give me your code if possable.

Comment: @Pieter what did you code in didselectrowatindexpath ?  After selecting a row try swipe up the table row and take into display again, and check if that make image again to actual place or remain indented.

Comment: I added cell code in my question for proper formatting. @Esha: funny thing is I did not have to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` in my code. Took the template for SplitViewController and elaborated on that.